# Using ngClass on an element that uses getElementById, element is null

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I've got an html element with `overflow: auto`, but I want to give it a border only when it's scrollable.

How do I evaluate the element's size from within ngClass without getting any kind of null errors?

Note: The element's enclosing div doesn't get rendered until after getting a response from an observable.

**Attempt 1:**

The html element is set up like this:

```
<div ngIf="!loading">
    <div id="{{someID}}" [ngClass]="{'border-class': isScrollable}"> ... </div>
</div>
```

In my ngOnInit, I call a function to see if the given element can be scrolled.

```
ngOnInit() {

     // this.loading gets set to false after an observable is returned

    /* ... */

    // scroll check
    let e = document.getElementById(`${this.someID}`);

    if (element !== null) {
        this.isScrollable = e.scrollHeight > e.clientHeight;
    }
}
```

If I don't check for null, I get errors. If I *do* check for null, then even if I have scrollable content, when the page is loaded, the border doesn't show up.

I thought the issue might be with this.loading, so I added the scroll check within the observable response, but after loading was set to false. Still no border.

**Attempt 2:**

`<div #textDiv [ngClass]="{'border-class': isScrollable}"> ... </div>`

```
@ViewChild('textDiv') element: ElementRef;

/* ... */

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isScrollable = this.element.scrollHeight > this.element.clientHeight;
}
```

But the border still doesn't show up on scrollable content when the page is loaded.

**Attempt 3:**

The only thing that has worked, is this hot mess:

```
setTimeout( () => {
    this.isScrollable = this.element.scrollHeight > this.element.clientHeight;
});
```

Is there a way I can get this to work without calling setTimeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<div ngIf="!loading">
    <div id="{{someID}}" [ngClass]="{'border-class': isScrollable}"> ... 
</div>
```

The `isScrollable` is not updating the value after it changes.

You can fix this, using a `get` and returning the value when ngAfterViewInit was already executed:

```
export class CustomComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    private afterViewInitExecuted = false;
    @ViewChild('textDiv') element: ElementRef;

    public get isScrollable() {
      if(this.afterViewInitExecuted) {
         return this.element.scrollHeight > this.element.clientHeight;
      }
      return false;
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.afterViewInitExecuted = true;
    }
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<div ngIf="!loading">
    <div id="{{someID}}" [ngClass]="{'border-class': isScrollable() }"> ... 
</div>
```

With that, it should work.

Comment: Even if I check for afterViewInitExecuted, I still get an error that says "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined". Instead I check for if (this.element) and that works! Thank you!